# SQLite Android Foreign Key

Tags: android, database, sqlite, foreign-keys, sqliteopenhelper

Hi guys I'm having a problem about my sqlite database Im trying to have a database with a foreign key. Now Im having trouble with this error it says that something about the insertion and also an error for the foreign key. Can you help me with this? here is my create table code and insertion code `enter code here`

```
    //Collection Create Table
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_COLLECTION = "CREATE TABLE "
        + COLLECTION_TABLE + "(" + COLLECTION_CODE + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + CUSTOMER_CODE
        + " TEXT," + TRANSACTION_CODE + " TEXT," + TIN + " TEXT," + OR_NO + " TEXT," + DATE
        + " TEXT," + AMOUNT_DUE + " TEXT," + AMOUNT_PAID + " TEXT," + REMARKS + " TEXT," + STATUS
        + " TEXT,"  + " FOREIGN KEY ("+CUSTOMER_CODE+") REFERENCES "+CUSTOMER_TABLE+" ("+CUSTOMER_CODE+"))";


public void addCollection(String collection_code, String customer_code, String transaction_code,
                          String tin, String or_no, String date, String amount_due, String amount_paid,
                          String remarks, String status) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLLECTION_CODE, collection_code);
    values.put(CUSTOMER_CODE, customer_code);
    values.put(TRANSACTION_CODE, transaction_code);
    values.put(TIN, tin);
    values.put(OR_NO, or_no);
    values.put(DATE, date);
    values.put(AMOUNT_DUE, amount_due);
    values.put(AMOUNT_PAID, amount_paid);
    values.put(REMARKS, remarks);
    values.put(STATUS, status);

    //inserting row
    long id = db.insert(COLLECTION_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();// closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "COLLECTION ADDED SUCCESSFULLY" + id);

}
```

and here is the error

[image]

Comment: Show the customer table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs saying you are probably violating the Sqlite foreign key constraint where you are "Attempting to insert a row into your COLLECTION_TABLE table that does not correspond to any row in your CUSTOMER(my guess) parent table".

Make sure that you have the *KEY in your CUSTOMER table, before you can insert values into COLLECTION_TABLE that is pointing to that *KEY. Hope this helps.

Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html